# How do I implement onSearchRequested in activity started by startActivityForResult

Tags: android

I need to pick a contact number to populate a number field in my main activity. I start another activity displaying a list of contact numbers using,
    `Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);  startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);`

I have the `onActivityResult()` method to parse the results. The problem is implementing a search method to search the list of contact numbers. I tried to use `onSearchRequested()` but this works for the Main activity.

Any idea on how do I implement `onSearchRequested()` for the activity spawned by the`contactPickerIntent` Intent.